# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined mysql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Everyone.
I make a small web-site for studying. I have met a problem. actually, It seems very simple error. but In case of me, It is a huge error.

On my system
ubuntu, node.js and mysql.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'Company'
});

var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080');
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  fs.readFile('list.html', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM products', function (error, results) {
       response.send(ejs.render(data, {
        data: results
      }));
    });
  });
});


app.get('/delete/:id', function(request, response) { 
  client.query('DELETE FROM products WHERE id=?', [request.param('id')], function() {
    response.redirect('/');
  });
});

app.get('/insert', function(request, response) { 
  fs.readFile('insert.html', 'utf8', function (error, data) {
  response.send(data);
  });
}); 

app.post('/insert', function(request, response) {
  var body = request.body;

  client.query('INSERT INTO products (name, modelnumber, series) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [
       body.name, body.modelnumber, body.series 
  ],function() {
    response.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

My error message is like title;TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I know where error is. app.post -> body.name, body.modelnumber, body.series..
 I tyed code with reading a book... 
I can't find why error come..

Answer (score 1):

From the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body):

> #### req.body
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is `undefined`, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer).
>
> This example shows how to use body-parsing middleware to populate req.body.
>
> ```
> var app = require('express')();
> var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
> var multer = require('multer'); 
>
> app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data
>
> app.post('/', function (req, res) {
>   console.log(req.body);
>   res.json(req.body);
> })
> ```

Learning from a book is often not enough, you should also read the documentation of libraries/modules you are using.